# How to identify encoding algorithm used

Tags: encryption, encodings

I'm using a calendar application, and each date is encoded. I would like to know which algorithm has been used to do this.

Example:

I have a date: 05-10-2023 ('mm-dd-yyyy') and it's encoded string is `f3fgJV/I6y7CXfdp2CgyPKG2qCVrHqVXAP6PVXd/HOs=`

This application is written in PHP, so there may be algorithms that I'm not aware of.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you base64 decode the value you get 32 bytes raw data which is way too much for a simple date. The length of 32 bytes can be an indicator that the data is encrypted using a block cipher (which usually process blocks of 128 bits = 16 bytes).

Comment: Any additional information - like another similar date, encoded tuple would give us better knowledge of the pattern. If its actually encrypted with a block cipher the output could vary.